# Return ordered dictionary to django template

Tags: json, django, nested, disqus

Suppose you want to display posts as in Disqus.
(It seems you can comment on any post in any depth)

How do I pass a such data to django template and let it draw the data as Disqus?

e.g. You want to display all posts which belong to a thread in a way which reveals the parent-child relationship.
How can you do that in django? (python/json/..)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/)? I have found that it works quite well for this type of tree structure.